# Grouping array of objects into nested maps

Tags: javascript, dictionary

```
var map = new Map();
[ { serverid: '21312412521312',
    userid: '32523523412123',
    text: 'a',
    name: 'foo' },
  { serverid: '21312412521312',
    userid: '32523523412123',
    text: 'b',
    name: 'bar' }].forEach(x => {
    map.set(x.serverid, new Map());
    (map.get(x.serverid)).set(x.userid, [x.name, x.text])
});
```

`map` ends up as:
`Map { '21312412521312' => Map { '32523523412123' => ['bar', 'b'] } }`
 why does this happen? I expected it to end up as:
 `Map { '21312412521312' => Map { '32523523412123' => ['foo', 'a'], ['bar', 'b'] } }`

Please do keep in mind this is only an example there will be more objects in the array. I'm trying to group them by serverid and userid in maps.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a *third* nested array or `Set` in order to contain multiple possible values for one `userid`, else your `.set(x.userid ...` will erase whatever previously existed at that userid index (which, here, is the `a` / `foo` on the second iteration).

```js
var map = new Map();
[{
    serverid: '21312412521312',
    userid: '32523523412123',
    text: 'a',
    name: 'foo'
  },
  {
    serverid: '21312412521312',
    userid: '32523523412123',
    text: 'b',
    name: 'bar'
  }
].forEach(x => {
  if (!map.has(x.serverid)) map.set(x.serverid, new Map());
  const serverMap = map.get(x.serverid);
  if (!serverMap.has(x.userid)) serverMap.set(x.userid, []);
  serverMap.get(x.userid)
    .push([x.name, x.text]);
});
// look in browser console, not in the snippet console, to see the structure:
console.log(map);
```